# bruto - gam mgcv pkg

Tags: gam, smoothing

I was reading the paper, Comparative performance of generalized additive models and multivariate adaptive regression splines for statistical
modelling of species distributions by J.R. Leathwick , J. Elith, T. Hastie.

It mentions that the bruto gam implementation in R ‘mda’ library, helps identify which variables to include in the final GAM model and also identifies the optimal degree of smoothing for each variable.

After looking at some examples, on the bruto implementation, I was able to determine that $type helps identify the variables in the GAM model.

However , I am not able to understand how bruto helps identify the degree if smoothing for each variable.

I was wondering if someone had tried this, and could help with an example.